# How Calculate Effect (percentage) label of the input variables on the output variable by BernoulliNB

Tags: machine-learning, python, naive-bayes-classifier, python-3.x

a description problem below. I have 10 words like X1 , X2 , X3 , ... , X10 
and three Label like short , long , hold.
My problem is that how calculate Effect (percentage) label of the input variables
by BernoulliNB Algorithm.

```
NB = BernoulliNB()
NB.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and how calculate Effect (percentage) label of the input variables

Comment: Are you asking for something like `NB.predict_proba(X_pred)`? From the documentation, this returns probability estimates for the vector `X_pred`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Naive Bayes model consists of the probabilities $P(X_i|Class)$ for every feature $X_i$ and every label $Class$. So by looking at the parameters of the model one can see *how important a particular feature is for a particular class*. the opposite could be calculated as well: $P(Class|X_i)$ represents the distribution of the classes given a feature.

Now at the level of individual instances it's not so clear what would be the "effect" of a particular feature: For every class the posterior probability is:

$$P(Class| X_1,..,X_n) = \frac{P(Class)\prod_i P(X_i|Class)}{P(X_1,..,X_n)}$$

You can easily order the features by how much they contribute to the prediction, i.e. the class which obtains the maximum posterior probability (for instance obtain the top 3 features). However you cannot quantify precisely the effect of each feature, because the prediction is not a linear combination of the features.

---

[Details added following comments]

Due to the NB assumption that features are independent, we have:

$P(Class|X_1,..,X_n) = \prod_i P(X_i|Class)$

$P(Class|X_1,..,X_n) = P(X_1|Class) * P(X_2|Class) * .. * P(X_n|Class)$

From the conditional definition:

$P(Class|X_1,..,X_n) = P(Class,X_1,..,X_n) / P(X_1,..,X_n)$

which gives:

$P(Class,X_1,..,X_n) = P(Class) * P(Class|X_1,..,X_n)$
$P(Class,X_1,..,X_n) = P(Class) * P(X_1|Class) * P(X_2|Class) * .. * P(X_n|Class)$

Now we use the marginal to calculate $P(X_1,..,X_n)$:

$P(X_1,..,X_n) = \sum_j P(Class_j,X_1,..,X_n)$
$P(X_1,..,X_n)  = P(Class_1,X_1,..,X_n) + .. + P(Class_n,X_1,..,X_n)$

So at the end we have $P(Class,X_1,..,X_n)$ and $P(X_1,..,X_n)$, so we can calculate:

$P(Class|X_1,..,X_n) = P(Class,X_1,..,X_n) / P(X_1,..,X_n)$

Note that if you do all these steps you should obtain the same probability for $P(Class|X_1,..,X_n)$ as the one returned by the function `predict_proba`.

**Caution**: the functions  `feature_log_prob_` and `class_log_prior_` don't give you the probability directly, they give you the logarithm of the prob. So you need to apply exponential in order to get back the probability.

Comment: thank you . how calculated with python?

Comment: @A.R.SEIF I'm not very familiar with python, sorry. Apparently you can access the parameter $P(class|X_i)$ in the attribute feature_log_prob_ and $P(Class)$ in class_log_prior_, see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.get_params.

Comment: thanks.Tell us about ∏i .

Comment: @A.R.SEIF what do you mean?

Comment: excusame @Erwan.in formula is ∏i.how can I get this amount ∏i?

Comment: Oh you mean the product: multiply all the values P(Xi|Class) together: P(X1|Class) * P(X2|Class) * P(X3|Class) * ... * P(Xn|Class)

Comment: thank you .very much

Comment: excusame @Erwan. in image [formula](https://play.min.io/seif/Capture.PNG?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F%2F20200623%2F%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200623T191850Z&X-Amz-Expires=432000&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=526b24d4dfea079858d7c2bb75b8f6a6f53e0606c2f0944673f405f6f96e5387) .i calculate a 1 by class_log_prior_.and 3 feature_log_prob_.my question is how calculate 2 and 4 .in image .thanks best regards

Comment: @A.R.SEIF I've added all the details in my answer. I don't think you need to do the full calculation for obtaining the "effect" of the features though, you could probably just use the parameters P(X|Class)... but that depends what you want to do exactly.